# Razor Pay integration with android (java)error: "android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>"

Tags: java, android, manifest, razorpay

I am trying to integrate payment method using "Razor Pay" payment gateway in android(Java), but each time error persists. The app itself, has nothing in it, I am just running the app after adding the razor pay dependency. I have tried several similar questions but they all say that explicitly add the 'android:exported="true" but then my app is running fine when I remove the  "**implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.12'**" from the build.gradle(app) file.  '

I followed the steps exactly from the razor pay documentation, this is the [LINK](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/build-integration/)

**This the error shown in the "Merged Manifest":**

"Merging Errors: 
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. My_Application_razor_pay.app main manifest (this file)"

**This the "AndroidManifest.xml" file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplicationRazorPay">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Any help would be great, thank you for your time.**

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.17'`

They have fix this problem:

[image]